# How do I import "com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer" into my Android Library?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, gradle, jar

I'm having issues getting the `UnityPlayer` dependencies into my Android Library plugin for Unity.

[image]

I just can't figure out the correct way to add dependencies to my plugin.

Before I was trying to add a `classes.jar` file to my `libs` directory that contains all the UnityPlayer code, and that got me to the point where I can write code without intellisense errors, but when I build and run I get this massive output.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.NativeLoader found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$10 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$11 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$12 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$13 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$14 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$15 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$16 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$17 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$18 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$19 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$2 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$3 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$4 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$5 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$6 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$7 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$8 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$9 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.a found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.a$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.a$2 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.a$a found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.b found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.c found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.d found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.e found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.f found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.g found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.h found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.i found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.j found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.k found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.k$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.l found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.m found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.n found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.o found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.p found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.q found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.q$1 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.q$2 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class com.unity3d.player.q$3 found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class org.fmod.FMODAudioDevice found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)
  Duplicate class org.fmod.a found in modules classes-2.jar (:coffeeplugin-release:) and unity-classes.jar (unity-classes.jar)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
]
stdout[
> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processReleaseManifest
> Task :processReleaseResources
> Task :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :compileReleaseSources
> Task :lintVitalRelease
> Task :mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :signingConfigWriterRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
19 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 12 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <f92457847c324e90907abe57dde6951d>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <f92457847c324e90907abe57dde6951d>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <f92457847c324e90907abe57dde6951d>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <f92457847c324e90907abe57dde6951d>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <f92457847c324e90907abe57dde6951d>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <f92457847c324e90907abe57dde6951d>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <f92457847c324e90907abe57dde6951d>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <f92457847c324e90907abe57dde6951d>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)
```

I'm seeing mostly duplicate errors, so I'm guessing I already have everything in the `classes.jar` in my Android Studio project. I built the project from an exported project from Unity and opened it in Android Studio then made the `"coffeeplugin"` module.

When I try to add `com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer` in the Gradle build script, Android Studio tells me its an invalid string when I sync Gradle.

[image]

I understand it's wanting `:SomeTag` I'm guessing, but I don't know what to put there.
The [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidJARPlugins.html) doesn't really get into this part (at least from what documentation and blogs I'm able to find).

coffeeplugin build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.unity3d.player'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

task copyPlugin(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn assemble
    from ('build/output/aar')
    into ('N:/Storage/UnityProjects/Coffee/Assets/Plugins/Android')
    include (project.name + "-release.aar")
}
```

Comment: Where does the UnityPlayer `classes.jar` come from in the first place? In my Unity project, there are no `.jar` files whatsoever.

Comment: Ah, I had not built to APK yet. When I did so, Unity generated `Temp/gradleOut/libs/unity-classes.jar`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out exactly what is contained in these AAR files I've been importing in to Unity.
I have been doing the correct thing by including `classes.jar` from Unity into my `plugin/libs`. The problem was that by building my plugin in Android Studio with `classes.jar` in `libs`, `classes.jar` was being included in the final AAR output, which on the Unity side of things is redundant because Unity already has this data, thus the duplicate classes error I've been getting.

The fix was to open the AAR is some archive editor (7-zip or winrar) and extract only the `clases.jar` within that and import only that into Unity.

[image]

I'm surprised there's not more official documentation on this process.

Also, this fix means no edits to the Gradle build script is necessary unless you want to automate the copy process from intermediate builds to Unity.

Comment: Just if someone is lost (like me 1 min ago), the final result should be to remove the .aar file from Unity project, and copy the extracted class.jar AND ALSO the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Can we get some clarity on this? Does this mean the proper way to create an Android Plugin for Unity is to create an existing Unity Android Project and build a module/library plugin from that project so that we can get a ref to the UnitplayerActivity/imports?

Or does that mean the best solution is to create a standalone library module/plugin android project, import the classes.jar from the respective Unity install path so that we can get our code to compile in Android studio and then gut the built .aar so that there isn't a duplicate reference to it?

Answer (score 7):

Change `implementation` to `compileOnly` for `'com.unity3d.player'`. This allows the unity player classes.jar to be used at compile time, but not at run time which was causing the duplication.

Answer (score 1):

What i did was renamed the Unity Jar [classes.jar] to [clases.jar]

[image]

and Added the following in Gradle file
[image]

**If this still gives the error then**:
Goto File>>Settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Opening the unity player class after adding classes.jar file from unity in libs folder solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle add line --> implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']).
And move your unity.jar to lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

I currently stumble into the same problem with a kotlin based solution.
After importing the classes.jar from
/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/{place_your_version}/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Variations/il2cpp/Development/Classes

I added the gradle instruciton:

```
implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
```