# How do I include an "implementation" dependency in my Gradle script with a JAR export?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, plugins

I'm writing a Android Unity plugin that uses [this library here](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android), and I'm having issues with getting this dependency to export with my JAR file of the whole plugin.

I've been following [this video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EElBAGkjPt4) on how to get a plugin working that communicates both ways between Android and Unity.

Previously in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59382250/how-do-i-import-com-unity3d-player-unityplayer-into-my-android-library/59395014#59395014), I was having issues with getting the Unity Classes JAR file into Android Studio so I can build the plugin. The video above showed that instead of importing the final AAR output into Unity, grab the JAR file from the intermediates dir and import that instead. This works when all the code is self-contained, but this particular JAR file doesn't have the [usb-serial-for-android](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android) library I need it to contain.

The video shows to have an include statement in the Gradle script that includes the `classes.jar` that contains the Unity code on the JAR export. I'm not including that because it works without it, and it creates the duplicate classes problem I had in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59382250/how-do-i-import-com-unity3d-player-unityplayer-into-my-android-library/59395014#59395014).

Now I'm trying to figure out in the Gradle script how to include the `com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:v2.1.0` dependency I have, but I'm not sure how. The previous include statement in the video is including a local JAR file. I have no knowledge how to do that with a github repo like I need it to.

I've tried the final AAR output again since it should contain usb-serial-for-android, but I'm running into the duplicate class problem again with the Unity code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 29
   buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"


   defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 17
      targetSdkVersion 29
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"

      testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
   }

   buildTypes {
      release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }

   afterEvaluate {
      assembleRelease.finalizedBy(exportJar)
   }

}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   }
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
   implementation 'com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:v2.1.0'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

task exportJar (type: Copy) {
   from('build/intermediates/packaged-classes/release/classes.jar')
   include('com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android') ???
   into('../../../UnityProjects/Coffee/Assets/Plugins/Android')
   rename('classes.jar', 'expressoplugin-release.jar')
}

task deleteOldJar (type: Delete) {
   delete '../../../UnityProjects/Coffee/Assets/Plugins/Android/expressoplugin-release.jar'
}

exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar)
```

I noticed that my exportJar task doesn't even seems to silently fail when the `include` statement uses "com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android" instead of "classes.jar".

Weirdly enough, this include statement doesn't even put everything in `classes.jar` into my exported JAR, so I'm not totally sure what I'm expecting it to do.

Error log when I try to instantiate my Java object containing usb-serial-for-android code doing the export without any include statement.

````
2019-12-18 15:35:38.669 25826-25860/com.vcom3d.coffeeunity E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/hoho/android/usbserial/util/SerialInputOutputManager$Listener;
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/hoho/android/usbserial/util/SerialInputOutputManager$Listener;
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source:72)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:405)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:32)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hoho.android.usbserial.util.SerialInputOutputManager$Listener
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379) 
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method) 
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source:72) 
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:405) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174) 
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:32) 
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00091] in <6084548bc46840b9ba4aa48ad550def0>:0 
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.NewObject (System.I
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a work-around getting to the library's JAR file. In the project navigator to the left, I went to project view on the drop down, scrolled down to where the library is, opened the file location on disk and just manually copied the JAR over to Unity.

[image]